# What happens to a mobile app if rewritten by new vendor

Tags: android, ios, mobile, web-applications, mobile-safari

We currently have a mobile app for our website.  It is a free news website with videos and articles.  The current mobile app is developed in house and is outdated.  We are looking to hire a third party vendor to rebuild the mobile app from the ground app.  Will the current end users need to uninstall the current mobile app and install the new one?  Is there a way to just force an update?  Looking for a solution that has the least impact to the end users.

Answer (score 0):

SHA1 fingerprint should be same in both application for that you can use the same `KeyStore` file which is used in old application while signing the apk file and make sure that `package id` for both application are same. If you have this application uploaded on Google PlayStore and can update it by uploading new version.